# How to address a recurring low temperature error seen at every boot-up?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, lsi, physical-environment

After updating to latest controller firmware, I started receiving the following error messages:

LSI 2208 ROC: Temperature sensor below error threshold on enclosure 1 Sensors 5 thru 7
[image: LSI MegaRAID Critical Error]

Is this something I should worry about, or is it a Red Herring?

Details: I have a Sans Digital NexentaSTOR 24-disk JBOD enclosure connected to LSI 9286-8e RAID-on-Chip controller with two SAS cables.  Seagate ES.2 3TB SAS hard drives populate every bay in the enclosure.

Comment: If you dismiss the alerts and reboot, do they come back? You could always check the storage manager for more information as well.

Comment: @NathanC Yes, it comes back.  What can I look at in MSM to get more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting virtual drive in LSI MegaRAID and re-creating it has solved this strange issue.